# Finding out which files are version controlled that now match the current .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

My organization made plenty of mistakes early on with git (storing binary objects, etc). We have re-done our .gitignore strategy to prevent binary objects (dll's, jars, zips) etc. from being committed.

What is the best way to identify files that are are currently version controlled, that would no longer be version controlled under the newly created .gitignore?

Comment: Shouldn't the title of this question be "Finding out which files are version controlled that *now match* the current .gitignore"?

Comment: Note that just adding an ignore pattern to `.gitignore` will not by itself remove a matching file from version control if it is already committed. You must specifically remove that file from version control, e.g. with `git rm --cached`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `ls-files`:

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-standard
```

This shows committed files that would be ignored by standard git rules (i.e. according to `.git/info/exclude`, `.gitignore` in each directory, and the user’s global exclusion file).

If you want to test a particular ignore file, you can use the `-X` parameter to specify the file:

```
git ls-files -i -X .\.gitignore
```